# PHP сессия .ASPXAUTH не сохраняется при использовании Curl

Tags: php, asp.net, curl, cookie

Я пытаюсь написать скрипт, который будет удобно выводить мои оценки с сайта университета, для этого я решил использовать PHP Curl.
Я написал скрипт, который посылает мои логин и пароль и еще некоторые генерируемые сайтом данные (которые как я заметил меняются каждые пару часов) на сервер университета. Мои скрипт работает правильно, и сайт даже выдает ошибку, если логин и пароль не правильны. НО Curl не сохраняет куку .ASPXAUTH именно которая отвечает за дальнейшую авторизацию на сайте.
Вот мой код:

```
$url = 'https://univer.kstu.kz/user/login';
$login = 'coxJoNRoDPJ.CFKTHDPf';
$password = 'CFErltAejrm';
$post = "login=".$login."&makelogin=1&password=".$password."&secret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
$userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko';

$curl = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,  dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

$html = curl_exec($curl);
echo $html;
```

Пожалуйста, не обращайте внимание на большую строку. Я меняю ее каждые пару часов, если скрипт не работает, так как не хочу ее парсить в ручную.

Comment: Укажите в ```CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR``` абсолютный путь.

Comment: Извините, можете написать как, но мне кажется дело не в этом, так как, файл с куки cookie.txt создается и туда записываются другие куки, кроме как я сказал .ASPXAUTH

Comment: Примерно так: ```curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__).'/home/user/foo/bar/baz/cookie.txt');``` т.е. укажите полный путь

Comment: Все траблы именно в точке (.).

Comment: а зачем это, мой скрипт и файл с куками находятся в одной директории

Comment: вы про точку перед ASPXAUTH говорите

Comment: Да, про неё говорю. Но я не уверен, и может вообще не то говорю. Но вы попробуйте указать полный путь к cookie.txt